# How to use intervalToDuration function from date-fns

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I tried using the intervalToDuration function from date-fns but I keep getting an error that says End Date is invalid.

My code is as follows

```
import { intervalToDuration} from "date-fns";

    remaining() {
          const now = new Date();
          const end = this.endDate;
          return intervalToDuration({
            start: now,
            end: end,
          });
        },
```

this.endDate is dynamically populated but for this question is equal to 2021-02-26T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: I think you need to show how your end date is dynamically generated. Where is endDate declared. Are you sure you are passing a date object and not a string for example?

Comment: @phenicie endDate comes from an api and it is a computed property.        
     `endDate() {
        const { timeAdded, endDate } = this.product;
        const auctionClose = addMinutes(new Date(endDate), timeAdded);
      return auctionClose;
    },

Answer (score 1):

Since your `endDate` variable is coming from an API, it is being stored as a string, not a date.

Calling `intervalToDuration` is expecting an [interval object](https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/Interval) to be passed as the parameter. An interval consists of two Dates or Numbers (unix timestamp)

To correct this, you must convert endDate to a date object, below is an untested example;

```
const remaining = () => {
  const endDate = "2021-02-26T00:00:00.000Z";
  const now = new Date();
  const end = new Date(endDate);
  return intervalToDuration({
    start: now,
    end: end
  });
};

const dur = remaining();
console.log("DURRATON ", JSON.stringify(dur));
//
// Response == DURRATON  {"years":0,"months":1,"days":8,"hours":15,"minutes":42,"seconds":0}
//
```

**Notice : This does not handle timezones correctly. `new Date()` will create a datetime in the client timezone where it appears that your response from the API is in GMT timezone**

Comment: Can you do `console.log(typeof this.endDate);` to see what type it is? I updated my answer above to show a working example using your string API response as endDate.

Comment: `console.log(typeof endDate)` returns object. `console.log(endDate instanceof Date)` returns true. The function returns the the correct answer but date-fns throws a error in the chrome console.